# IndexError: string index out of range.. Why?

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to find the last white space of the string, and them break it there.
line_size  is the size that the line has to be, so it varies.

```
if line[line_size] != ' ':
        for x in reversed(range(line_size)):
            print line[x]
            if line [x] == ' ':
            break_line = line[x]
```

Answer (score 6):

you should use `rfind` for the same

```
In [71]: l = "hi there what do you want"

In [72]: l.rfind(' ')
Out[72]: 20
```

`rfind` Return the highest index in the string where substring sub is found

the problem in your case seems to be with `line_size` you can go for `reversed(range(len(l)))`

```
In [76]: for x in reversed(range(len(l))):
   ....:     if l[x] == ' ':
   ....:         print x
   ....:         break
   ....:
20
```

Answer (score 0):

Indices in Python are zero-based, so if `line_size = len(line)` (the number of characters in `line`), then the last character of `line` is `line[line_size-1]`.

Comment: Ah, first statement, I see it now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `line_size = len(line)`, this will always fail

```
if line[line_size] != ' ':
```

because the first item is `line[0]`, the last item is `line[len(line)-1]`